# Why reestablish Egypt's borders?

Tags: plagues-makkos, va-eira

[Rabbeinu Bechaya Shemos (7:27)](https://www.sefaria.org/Shemot_Rabbah.10.2?lang=bi&with=Rabbeinu%20Bahya%7CQuoting&lang2=en&p3=Rabbeinu_Bahya%2C_Shemot.7.27.1&lang3=bi) quotes the Shemos Rabbah (10:2) saying the plague of tzfarde'ah reestablished the borders between Cush and Egypt

> בני חם ובני מצרים היו חלוקים בתחומין הכושיים אומרים ע"כ תחומנו
> והמצריים אומרים ע"כ תחומנו כיון שבאו הצפרדעים עשו שלום ביניהם הגבול
> שלא היו צפרדעים בו היו יודעים שאינו של מצרים שנאמר את כל גבולך ולא של
> אחרים - this area had remained disputed between them until that time.
> Due to the plague of the frogs they made peace amongst themselves.
> They came to the realisation that the area not invaded by the frogs
> belonged to the territory of Cham. We derive this from the words of
> Moses’ warning “your entire territory,” i.e. not anyone else’s
> territory.

What is the lesson of this seemingly irrelevant, albeit related, consequence included in the Torah's explanation of the plague? (If anything, it would seem that making peace with a rival country would be a welcomed element of the plague)

Comment: Is that your translation? You/someone seems to have translated "שאינו של מצרים" as "belonged to the territory of Cham".

Comment: @msh210 It's from the link in Sefaria - agreed it's unusual, though I have had Rebbeim refer to Mitzriyim as Bnei Cham, so I saw no need to alter.

Answer (score 1):

I have no source for this idea, it's just a s'vara I had upon reading the midrash:

Indeed, I think the intent of the midrash is to point to a welcomed element of plague, as you put it. I think the midrash is hinting towards an idea that's similar to multiple midrashim that say that when X did Y, this brought about Z. For example, the gemara in [Shabbat 56b](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shabbat.56b.14?vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Vocalized_Aramaic&lang=bi) (and similarly brought in a number of other midrashim) says:

> "Rav Yehuda said that Shmuel said: When Solomon married Pharaoh’s daughter, the angel Gabriel descended from heaven and implanted a reed into the sea, and a sandbar grew around it, growing larger each year, and upon it the great city of Rome was built, which became God’s instrument to punish Israel."

Except that in the case of this midrash, A and B did something good which resulted in C - the Egyptians and the Cushim made peace among themselves, and what did that result in? The rise of Shishak.

Let me explain:

[Rabbi Ahron Marcus](https://www.thelehrhaus.com/scholarship/ahron-marcus-the-leading-hasidic-zionist-scholar-of-ancient-judaism-you-never-heard-of/) wrote in an essay called "Of The Jewish Chronology" that Shishak (already then (early 20th century) identified with Pharaoh [Shoshenq](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoshenq_I)), the king of Egypt who had invaded Eretz Yisrael in the time of Rechav'am,  was Ethiopian,
and that Zerach the Cushi, [who fought King Asa](https://www.sefaria.org.il/II_Chronicles.14.8?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), was Shishak's son-in-law. Modern scholarship identifies Shishak/Shoshenq as Libyan in origin, but I think that Rabbi Marcus's point still stands: Shishak managed a very successful campaign during his time as king because he led a unified Egypt: Egyptians, Cushim and Libyans (Luvim in Tanach) fighting along one another under one banner. Shishak's army was successful in [annexing territories as far as Syria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoshenq_I#Foreign_policy).

Why did the Egyptians under Shishak merit such strength? In my opinion, based on the midrash, because at a time of hardship, during the makot, the Egyptians and Cushim decided to set aside their differences and make peace (and that during the time of Asa the reason they lost was because Yehudah's merit at the time was greater).

The bottom line of the midrash seems to be that making peace, especially during hard times, is a catalyst for good things to come, even if the reward may be far in the future.

Answer (score 1):

So I saw a very nice idea [here](https://midrasha.biu.ac.il/node/966) from Rav Matania Yedid of Bar Ilan

He asks your exact question and explains that the purpose of mentioning this side point is to demonstrate the overarching Hashgacha (Providence) of Hashem in that the plague was designed to not only punish but also bring peace and therefore show the all-powerful might of G-d.

The understanding being; that it was to act as a hint to Pharoah about what would be if he followed the direction of Hashem i.e. that whilst the frogs were indeed scattered on all the borders of Egypt, at the same time it could create peace with its neighbours, a hint from above to the possibility of civil war or world peace.

He notes from Rav Tzadok of Lublin in his sefer [Machshavos Charutz](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14375&st=&pgnum=46&hilite=) (letter ches-8) that Egypt's border was very narrow compared to the sea which is a great expanse. As per its name it is מיצר - narrow and constricted. Hashem was therefore teaching Egypt to discern the right borders, and not to spread beyond their borders. The slavery of the Jewish people was beyond the limit they deserved and therefore in the end the Egyptians were unable to restore them to their harsh servitude and even go as far as pursuing them to the Yam Suf. The result is that Hashem drowns these borders in the sea. Meaning, what began with the plagues of the frogs marking the borders, ends in the Red Sea with the complete blurring of the straits/borders/limits. And this is the message of the Pesach story that everyone can overcome there own personal limits and boundaries.

Answer (score 1):

The [Artscroll Midrash Rabbah](https://www.artscroll.com/Books/9781422614563.html) series on Shemos Rabbah (10:2) offers an unsourced footnote which addresses this question saying the borders of what belongs to one person and what belongs to another person are often unclear as we believe their good fortune comes at our own expense. However, when they suffer misfortune then the boundaries of life become clear since the Almighty is the one Who gives talent and resources as well as carefully measures suffering within each individual's "borders."